# Merge borders among DIV

Tags: html, css

Here you go:

```
<div id="weapons_main">
  <div class="col1">.</div>
  <div class="col1">.</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#weapons_main{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: thin solid #869BBF;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
}

#weapons_main div{
    background-color: #EFF0FB;
    border: solid 5px red;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#weapons_main .col1{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T3v9u/

the problem is seen immediatly: the red lines are thicker than they should, because browser summarise them instead of merging it. How to dodge it?

Comment: If I get what you're trying to do, why not use `table`s instead of `div`s?

Comment: lolololol I was just ordered not to use table but div construction instead. But good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work with `:last-child` and the adjacent sibling selector (+)

```
#weapons_main div:last-child {
    border-top: 0;
}


#weapons_main .col1 + .col1 {
    border-left: 0;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/T3v9u/1/)

For a more advanced example you could work with `:nth-child`

```
#weapons_main .col1:nth-child(2n) {
    border-left: 0;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/T3v9u/3/)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
#weapons_main
{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: thin solid #869BBF;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 80%;
}

#weapons_main div
{
    background-color: #EFF0FB;
    border-top: solid 5px red;
    border-left: solid 5px red;
    border-right: solid 5px red;
    border-bottom: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#weapons_main div:last-child
{
    border-bottom: solid 5px red;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#weapons_main .col1
{
    border-bottom: solid 5px red;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/7Yw4C/

```
#weapons_main .col1:first-child
{
    border-right: none;
}

#weapons_main .col1:last-child
{
    border-left: none;
}
```

Additional: http://jsfiddle.net/7Yw4C/1/

Answer (score 2):

To support IE8 you need to use `:first-child`

Sample:

```
#weapons_main div:first-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this approach:

```
display: table;
```

for the container and

```
display: table-row;
```

for divs which are going to hold row content and

```
display: table-cell
```

for cell divs

Comment: and than `border-collapse: collapse;` is going to work.